# Why doesn't Visual Studio auto increment your version number?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This question asked how to auto update version number in VS 2010 : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025704/publishing-in-net-produces-application-files-myapp-someversionnumber-how-to-ge

The answer was, 
You have to update both Assembly Version AND File version manually

Shouldn't the version number increment each time I publish?  Why should I do it manually?  Is this is a conscious decision by MS to do it this way? What's the thinking behind having people manually update their own version number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So two or more developers can publish their code under the same version.

Comment: Your answer seems to contain serious ambiguity. Shouldn't *different versions* published by different developers have **different** version numbers?

Comment: @altern - what you are saying may be a better practice these days, but that doesn't mean Visual Studio adheres to it. Offering this kind of flexibility gives more control to the dev/dev team. From a release/marketing standpoint, you may want to have everything as of today called 2.0 and not 2.013.

Answer (score 9):

You could always use the ["Build Version Increment"](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/) open source add-on for visual studio to do it for you.

> ...I've tested the addin with Visual Studio 2005/2008 on C#, VB.NET and C++.NET projects under Windows XP/Vista SP1.
>
> #### Functionality
>
> - Different auto increment styles can be set per major, minor, build or revision number.
> - Supports C#, VB.NET and C++.NET projects.
> - Not required to be installed by all project members. Configuration is shared via properties in the solution and project files. Developers who don't have the addin won't feel a thing.
> - Automatically checks out required files if under source control.
> - Can be configured per solution and/or per project.
> - Can be configured to update only on certain configuration builds (debug, release, any or custom)
> - Can update assembly attributes in an external source file instead of the default AssemblyInfo...

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Studio does update your version number automatically.**  If you code `AssemblyVersion("a.b.*")`, every build will get a different number `a.b.c.d`, and every build number will be greater than all older builds.  It just isn't a monotonically-increasing system like most of us expect.  Instead, the trailing two components, `c.d` will be computed based on the current date and time.